# Missing background color in CKeditor in print preview

Tags: printing, colors, background, ckeditor

Im using ckeditor 4,

I create a div with a 'style definition' and apply to a line in ckeditor. it works very well.

The problem is, when i do print preview the background color went missing.

This is my style definition:

```
    {
    name: 'Warning',
    element: 'div',
    styles: {
            'background-color': '#ffdddd',
            'border-left': '6px solid #f44336',
            'margin-bottom': '15px',
            'padding': '4px 12px'
    }
},
```

Showing in ckeditor :[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33pAb.png), background-color visible

In print preview:[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4dXK.png), missing background-color

Thanks in adv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realize the checkbox which allows us to include the background graphic/color in print preview. When you print preview, the checkbox located at the bottom most of the print preview side-bar. hope this will help.

Comment: Binoy, you are a live saver. 

If you stumble upon this, make sure to load CkEditor's CSS as part of your stylesheet for the iFrame print preview. That way the browser will use the right colors.